# Add right detail to table view cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I cannot seem to work out how to add text in a different colour to the right side of my table view cell. Here is the code I have added.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *informationTableIdentifier = @"InformationCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:informationTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:informationTableIdentifier];
}

[cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
[cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];


if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [infoCellFirstSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    if (indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 3) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"@SykesHarvey";
        [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.48 green:0.93 blue:0.25 alpha:1.0]];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:informationTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [infoCellSecondSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3) {
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
        [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [infoCellThirdSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
if (indexPath.section == 3) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [infoCellFourthSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
if (indexPath.section == 4) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [infoCellFifthSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
}
```

All this is presenting is [image] but I want it to say @SykesHarvey on the right side of the Developer cell. Please can someone help?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing: In your case with issue, you are doing right after you tried to set the detailsText you are doing a whole new alloc/init for the cell? Note that `cell.detailsText` should be `nil` because there is no `detailsText` with `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`

Comment: Can you explain in detail? Exactly What's your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reseting the cell detailTextLabel by reinitialise it in next line.
I have optimise your code a little. Try this :

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *informationTableIdentifier = @"InformationCell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:informationTableIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:informationTableIdentifier];
  }
  [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
  [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

  switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = [infoCellFirstSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        break;
    case 1:
        if (indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 3) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:informationTableIdentifier];
            [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
            [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"@SykesHarvey";
            [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.48 green:0.93 blue:0.25 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [infoCellSecondSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        break;
    case 2:
        if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3) {
            [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
            [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
            cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [infoCellThirdSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        break;
    case 3:
        cell.textLabel.text = [infoCellFourthSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        break;
    case 4:
         cell.textLabel.text = [infoCellFifthSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        break;
    default:
        break;
  }

  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```